# How to avoid qmake Build Step if using QT Creator

Tags: makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I have a Qt project file (.pro) and a Makefile (self-written).
The project file is simply used for editing the source files in the IDE:

```
/home/project/

             ./src/fooApp.pro
                              TEMPLATE=app
                              CONFIG-=qt
                              TARGET=fooApp

                              SOURCES+=...
                              HEADERS+=...

             ./src/main.c
             ./src/foo.c
             ./src/foo.h

             ./build/Makefile
```

I would like to build the project via IDE **QT Creator 3.5.1**
Therefore I would like to invoke make on the Makefile.

**During the build process I always get the error that no Makefile can be found hence no build was triggered.**

The solution is to always invoke qmake first, then make (even if a Makefile is still present and custom setting `make -C ../build in /home/project/`)

Could someone please explain, why it is not possible ignore qmake and directly invoke make on the already existing Makefile?

(No Qt library is used for the project)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy, I use makefile only project alot because I like qt-creator as an IDE. In the IDE goto the projects tab on the left.

Select the "build" tab near the top of that page, looks like: `(build | run)`.

In the build steps:

- remove the qmake build step by press hovering the mouse over that step and clicking the X that appears.
- Edit the `build directory` so that it is the same directory as your makefile.

  **Note:** you will have to click the `shadow build` check box next to it to enable it.
- remove any other steps you don't want (infact just remove them all for now).
- Add a new step `make` step. It will try to use the default make, but you can override that if you want. Also add any arguments like `debug` or `-j4` etc...

Then you are done :)

Next time you hit build it will simply invoke that make command.

**Note:** You will need to do the same for any other configurations you have (like release, debug, etc...). You can also just add loads more configurations for doing other make options (if you have them) for instance `make doxygen` or such...

Just remembered you can also either:

- I am not sure why, but when I tested it (as OP did) you can't seem to just setup a `make` step with parameters `-C ../`, it seems to want to look in the "build directory" first.

I tend to use the build location since its a nice feature of the IDE.

**Note** an issue with newer versions of Qtcreator as a makefile IDE is that you cant share your build settings with other people (i.e. can't configure control them) because they are locked to your PC profile... long story... but its very sad and I no longer use qt creator for that one reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however I was expecting this help.

The problem is, I already tried your approach but it did not worked for me.
I deleted the qmake step due to the fact that I already have a Makefile.
Added `-C` option to `make` arguments.

However the IDE still claimed about not finding my Makefile. 

Is it because the Makefile is not located in the same dir as the .pro file?

Comment: @xelA yes probably. If you update your question with the locations of your .pro file and your makefile we can sort that really easily. Did you see the little box called `build location` (or somthing like that) - this is the path that will be used to run `make` in. Also do you have a file called `Makefile` or `makefile`? if its anything else then you need to specify the name by doing `make -f my_makefile.mk` or such...  Note: you can add another custom step and run `pwd` to see which folder you start in (might need to remove the make step if its not working and re-add it later).

Comment: I have updated the project structure above.

The `.pro` file is located in `/src/` and the `Makefile` is located in `/build` directory.

As mentioned one workaround is to add a dummy Makefile in the directory where the `.pro` file resides.
However even if no qmake Build Step is active this dummy file is needed and this is confussing me.

( `make` is called with the `-C ../build` option i.e. where my Makefile is)

For me it seems to be that Qt Creator always expects a `Makefile` next to the `.pro` file during build, even if its just a dummy.

Comment: @xelA and what is your `build location` set to in your build config? - you won't need the `-C ...` part if you fill that in correctly - that will be your start directory. You may need to set it to `../build` or somthing

Comment: The build directory (i.e. project root) seems to be automatically the directory where the `.pro`file is located.
I cannot change it in the `Build-Steps` pane (greyed out till I activate the `Shadow build`) Is this the mentioned "`build location`" you mean?

Comment: Yes that is the one - I had forgotten that you need to click shadow build (its not really the official use of it - but it'll do what you want). Incidentally I did try the `-C ../` and you are right that does not seem to work, but the build location method does (just re-tested it) - but as you say you need to click the shadow build option and then enter the path you want. Note: you can enter `../` there if you want. To test where you are put `pwd` into the make override command (so that when you build it runs pwd and prints the directory. But I just moved my makefile up a level and tried it.

Comment: >>> I can agree with you last post. 
I finally got it compiled with the `Shadow build` enabled option pointing to the location where my Makefile is (without the need for an dummy `Makefile` immediately beside the `.pro` file).

Could add that `Shadow build` hint to your answer above. 
I will meanwhile mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xelA good point - I  have updated - please check you are happy with that.